# Python - global variable is not defined (but it is)

Tags: python, json, csv, import

So I'm working on this file that converts a CSV to JSON, however I keep getting this error message but can't seem to figure it out. Indentation seems to be correct so I'm a bit lost on where to go with it. Code is below:

**Traceback** (most recent call last):

```
  File "/home/uwp/widgets/contentFreshness/freshmap.py", line 308, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/uwp/widgets/contentFreshness/freshmap.py", line 303, in main
    mySite.writeJSONFile(options)
  File "/home/uwp/widgets/contentFreshness/freshmap.py", line 247, in writeJSONFile
    outputFile.write('"' + str(dateOfCrawl) + '"' )
NameError: global name 'dateOfCrawl' is not defined
```

**Code**

```
class Site:

    dateOfCrawl = 0;

    def __init__(self,csvFilePath):
        self.pageList = [] # ordered list of page IDs
        self.pageData={} # dictionary of individual page dictionaries, indexed on page ID
        self.titleDict = { } # dictionary of unique titles
        self.buildPageData(csvFilePath)
        self.homePageId=self.pageList[0] # only use of site.pageList
        self.depth=0

    def buildPageData(self,csvFilePath):
        global dateOfCrawl
        # read data from CSV file, build a dictionary of page data, including list of children, in order
        lines = csv.reader(open(csvFilePath, "rb"))
        for line in lines:
            pageURL=line[0]
            pageURL=re.sub('\/\Z', '',pageURL) # remove any trailing slash
            self.pageData[pageURL]={}
            self.pageData[pageURL]["URL"]=pageURL
            self.pageData[pageURL]["Title"]=self.cleanTitle(line[1],pageURL)

            # when taking the home page and chop its url the parent will be http:/
            # which should be avoided by setting it to ''
            parent = chopPath(pageURL)
            if(parent == 'http:/'):
                parent=''
                dateOfCrawl = line[2]
            self.pageData[pageURL]["Parent"]= parent
            self.pageData[pageURL]["Modified"]=line[2]
            self.pageData[pageURL]["Children"]=[] 

        list = self.pageData.keys()

        # sort IDs before attempting to match children
        self.pageList = self.pageData.keys()
        self.pageList.sort()

        lineCount = 0       
        for pageURL in self.pageList:
            # record page as child of its parent (parents must already be in the list!)
            parentURL=self.pageData[pageURL]["Parent"]

            if (lineCount > 0):
                while( self.pageData.has_key(parentURL)== False):
                    if(parentURL == ''):
                        sys.exit(pageURL + " has no parent at " + parentURL)
                    parentURL = chopPath(parentURL)
                self.pageData[parentURL]["Children"].append(pageURL)

            lineCount+=1
        self.pageCount=lineCount

    def writeJSONFile(self,options):
        global dateOfCrawl
        outputFile = options ["outputFile"]
        #see http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#DataTable
        outputFile.write('[')
        outputFile.write('"' + str(dateOfCrawl) + '"' )
        self.homePage.toJSON(options)
        outputFile.write(']')
        outputFile.close()
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide the full traceback. You are asking people to read though 200+ LOC to help you - help yourself first.

Comment: Ah apologies, thought I had included it! I know it's a lot of code, but to get an understanding it may be necessary.

Comment: That is **almost never the case**. Please read http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and take more time to narrow down the issue in the future.

Comment: Definitely will do, again, apologies for the ignorance and I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: I have trimmed down your post to only the necessary bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign `dateOfCrawl = 0;` (please read [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) as a *class attribute*. For some reason, you are also mixing in a `global`, which is completely separate. It is not really clear why `dateOfCrawl` should be a class (rather than instance) attribute, or why you also have the `global`. You should probably just:

1. Make it an instance attribute (move `dateOfCrawl = 0` inside `__init__`); then
2. Access *that* in the other methods (`self.dateOfCrawl`).

Comment: Thank you, that solved this issue, opened a whole bunch of others but progress is progress! :).

Answer (score 0):

You can access this variable this way:

```
Site.dateOfCrawl
```

[Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

You need to define `global dateOfCrawl`. Move `dateOfCrawl = 0;` inside `__init__` of `Site` class, to be like this:

```
class Site:
    def __init__(self,csvFilePath):
        global dateOfCrawl
        dateOfCrawl = 0
        ....
```